# Struct with unnamed members of fixed size

Tags: c++, struct

I'm parsing some structures for a game. I know most things about the structures, but there are various things I don't know, nor do I really care about them. But I need them in my parsing so things line up. For example:

```
template <unsigned int Size>
class unknown
{
    BYTE data[Size];
};

struct s_object
{
    int stuff;
    unknown<100> unk1;
    int otherstuff;
    unknown<200> unk2;
};
```

This is a contrived example but it shows what I'm trying to do. I don't like having to name members `unk1` and then `unk2`. Ideally I'd like to do this

```
 struct s_object
    {
        int stuff;
        unknown<100>;
        int otherstuff;
        unknown<200>;
    };
```

But of course that doesn't work. Is there a way for the compiler to either generate a random name, use no name, or maybe just treat it as padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__COUNTER__` macro (but will need some preprocessor trickery). It is implemented by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), [Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and probably others.

You can then define a macro named, for example `_` that expands to something like `_unused_15`,  `_unused_16` and so on upon use. With it your code will become:

```
struct s_object
{
    int stuff;
    unknown<100> _;
    int otherstuff;
    unknown<200> _;
};
```

The trickery being, i.e.

```
#define CAT(a,b)           a##b
#define CAT_DELAYED(a,b)   CAT(a,b)
#define _                  CAT_DELAYED(_unused_,__COUNTER__)
```

Answer (score 2):

**edit**: even GCC doesn't let you do this!  Corrected.

In general, no.  You could hack together a macro using `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and/or `__COUNTER__`  (the latter being another compiler extension, but supported on GCC and MSVC among others) to name the fields for you, if you *really* wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must do this "automatcially", something like this would work:

```
#define UNKNOWNY(line, size) char unknown_##line[(size)]
#define UNKNOWNX(line, size)  UNKNOWNY(line, size)
#define UNKNOWN(size)   UNKNOWNX(__LINE__, size)
```

But I don't really see how that is much better than just writing `char unknown1[100]`. It's not that much longer you know - and you can always copy/paste.

Edit: add extra level of `#define`.

Comment: It's not for ease of typing, it's so it's more maintainable. Otherwise I need to manage the unknown numbers myself (unk1, unk2 etc). I've tried that example and __LINE__ isn't being expanded into its actual line number, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Updated - I tested it this time. You need two levels of macro expansion for it to work - first level just makes __LINE__.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but it cannot be done
you most define name!